# Gitlab proxied SSL (Docker) certificate verification failed

Tags: git, docker, ssl, nginx, gitlab

I have a self-hosted Gitlab omnibus installation behind a Nginx reverse proxy (both docker container). Everything works fine in the browser however when I try to clone a repository I get the following error:

```
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

**Nginx config**

```
upstream gitlab{
  server gitlab:80;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

# HTTP server to redirect all 80 traffic to SSL/HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ${DOMAIN_NAME};

    # Tell all requests to port 80 to be 302 redirected to HTTPS
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    server_name ${DOMAIN_NAME};

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/${SSL_CERT};
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/${SSL_CERT_KEY};

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128...';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location /gitlab {
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_hide_header 'X-Frame-Options';
    }
}
```

**Gitlab config**

```
external_url 'https://${DOMAIN_NAME}/gitlab/'
[...]
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['ssl_ciphers'] = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128...'
nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
"X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
"X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the certificate, you need to provide the CA fullchain (your browser doesn't need it necessarily but curl/git/etc do)

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in terminal for ubuntu

`export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1`

Comment: Users shouldn't need to do that... I finally found the solution cf my answer

Comment: Disabling SSL verification is not a solution! It's only a bad workaround.